# mysqli UNION and ORDER of all result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data from two table order by date:

```
(SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3);
```

This return 3 items from news order by date then 3 items from article order by date:

```
- news 1 (2018-8-22)
- news 2 (2018-7-19)
- news 3 (2018-6-13)
- article 1 (2018-8-22)
- article 2 (2018-7-18)
- article 3 (2018-6-12)
```

But I want to combine data order by date like this:

```
- news 1 (2018-8-22)
- article 1 (2018-8-22)
- news 2 (2018-7-19)
- article 2 (2018-7-18)
- news 3 (2018-6-13)
- article 3 (2018-6-12)
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add an outer select:

```
select * from
(SELECT * FROM news  LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM article  LIMIT 3) as x
ORDER BY date DESC
```